# Path variables not working on 0.6.5 e.g. METEOR_SETTINGS

Tags: meteor

i cannot get it working after i updated to 0.6.5.

I created a new meteor project.

I have a start.sh script that looks like this.

```
export METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat ./settings.json)
meteor
```

settings.json:

```
{
  "public":{
    "bla":"blup"
  }
}
```

Meteor.settings on the client is undefined. It works if i add the settings json file via "--settings", but unfortunately this is not what i need.

The PORT environment variable or NODE_ENV also does not work for me.

Adding some random stuff like "export MY_ENV_VAR=foo" however works.

Am i missing s.th.? It all worked well before. I would really appreciate your help.

Thx!

(also created an issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1381)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to test your meteor app locally (dev mode) or you want to deploy your app to the Meteor hosting, then just pass the file path as settings param:

```
meteor --settings settings.json
```

In case of running from bundle on your own server, then you need the environment variable.

[Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settings).

Comment: This is the clearest note I've seen about how to do this, thank you. Your note the "dev mode" means any time you're not using a compiled bundle was very helpful.